# I am not getting expected response from Curl request in PHP

Tags: php, curl, postman, libcurl, php-curl

I have a curl request which is working fine in https://reqbin.com/ and in the Postman but when I implement same in PHP it is not working; Below is plain CURL command;

```
curl -X POST \
'http://example.com' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-d '{"Header": {"Token": "xyz"}, "Body": {"Email": "abc@gmail.com", "FirstName": "test", "Surname": "test"}}'
```

The response I am getting from this is;

```
{"Header":{"Status":"OK"},"Body":{"BackUrl":"https:example.com","Redirect":"YES"}}
```

But when I implement same in PHP as;

```
$curl = curl_init();
$headers = array(
    "content-type: application/json"
);

$postData = '{"Header": {"Token": "xyz"}, "Body": {"Email": "abc@gmail.com",  "FirstName": "test", "Surname": "test"}}';

$opt_arr = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://example.com',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
);
curl_setopt_array($curl, $opt_arr);
echo $resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

I do not receive the expected response;

```
{"Header":{"Status":"ERROR","ErrorMsg":"INVALID_REQUEST"},"Body":{"BackUrl":"","Redirect":"NO"}}
```

I need help converting the above working curl to the correct PHP code.

Comment: *But when I implement same in PHP* The code for PHP is not identical to the command. `"Header": {"Token": "xyz"}` is sent differently.

Comment: @273K Even if I wrap header & body and send it as a whole `$postData = '{"Header": {"Token": "xyz"}, "Body": {"Email": "abc@gmail.com",  "FirstName": "test", "Surname": "test"}}';
` I am getting same error.

Comment: Show you attempt in the code. Don't use the comments for that.

Comment: @273K I have found the solution, I was missing https in URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many unsuccessful attempts in PHP, I tried to implement it in javascript and here I got to know that error is with SSL security, hence I added HTTPS into the URL, and it worked.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$headers = array(
    "content-type: application/json"
);

$postData = '{"Header": {"Token": "xyz"}, "Body": {"Email": "abc@gmail.com",  "FirstName": "test", "Surname": "test"}}';

$opt_arr = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
);
curl_setopt_array($curl, $opt_arr);
echo $resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with PHP, regardless of that I see a difference in sending `"Header": {"Token": "xyz"}`. The curl command sends it in the post data, whereas PHP sends it in the http headers. The PHP variables should be

```
$headers = array(
    "content-type: application/json"
);
$postDataHeader = array(
    'Token' => 'xyz'
);
$postDataBody = array(
    'Email' => 'abc@gmail.com',
    'FirstName' => 'test',
    'Surname' => 'test'
);
$postData = json_encode(array(
    'Header' => $postDatHeader,
    'Body' => $postDataBody
));
```

and $postData must be set in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, not CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.

fixed PHP example:

```php
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://example.com',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'content-type: application/json'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array(
        'Header' => array(
            'Token' => 'xyz',
        ),
        'Body' => array(
            'Email' => 'abc@gmail.com',
            'FirstName' => 'test',
            'Surname' => 'test',
        ),
    ), JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR)
));
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: yup you're very close. he also needs to put $postData in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS rather than CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER :)

Comment: should i fix your answer or make one myself? hmm